# Changing interactive input program to command line input

Tags: python

I wrote a program that collects some numbers from the user and prints our the smallest. Here is that program:

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
     if (numbers[i] < smallest):
        smallest = numbers[i]
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

Now from everybody's answers I have gotten to this point.

import sys
from List import *

```
def main():
   strings = ArrayToList(sys.argv[1:])
   numbers = ListMap(int,strings)
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
      if (numbers[i] < smallest):
         smallest = numbers[i]
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

I get the error:

```
File "command.py", line 12, in <module>
   main()
File "command.py", line 9, in main
   if (numbers[i] < smallest):
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

Now I am supposed to use the extreme pattern for lists to find and print the smallest integer after the ListMap has converted the arguments into ints. Can anyone help me more to finish this program?

Comment: What do you want the commandline to look like?  `sys.argv` holds the "raw" commandline.

Comment: python3 command.py 11 5 3 51

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.argv` : it gives you the list of arguments you passed to your program.

```
import sys

def main():
   # converts the argv strings into a list of int
   numbers = [int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:] # first value is the name of the program itself
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
     if (numbers[i] < smallest):
        smallest = numbers[i]
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

Now the really pythonic way is :

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(min([int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]))
```

1. `if __name__ == '__main__'` is good way to define your program entry point as the **name** symbol is set to '**main**' the module is directly executed (not imported from another module)
2. min(iterable) returns the minimum value of an iterable
3. print() (not just print) makes it python 3 compatible

Comment: Careful, you're comparing them as strings, not as numbers.  (`'10' < '9'`)

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is the way to go about:

**Example Program:**

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

**Running:**

```
$ python3 myscript.py this is cool
['this', 'is', 'cool']
```

**Your script:**

```
import sys

def main():
   numbers = sys.argv[1:]
   smallest = numbers[0]
   for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
     if (int(numbers[i]) < smallest):
        smallest = (numbers[i])
   print("The smallest number is: ", smallest)
main()
```

**Runs as:**

```
$ python3 myscript.py 11 5 3 51
The smallest number is: 3
$
```

**To convert to an integer, type `int(variable)`, just surround your variable with `int()`**

Comment: It gives me 11 as the smallest number instead of 3. Any idea why?

Comment: The elements of sys.argv are strings, and they need to be converted to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `argparse` module to handle command line input.  It is not so difficult to use, and it gives you the benefit of parsing simple input (such as a list of integers) for you.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(  # this is the main class of argparse
    description='collect some numbers and print out the smallest')
parser.add_argument(
    'numbers',    # the name of this command line argument 
    nargs='+',    # this '+' means it can be repeated (appear multiple times)
    metavar='N',  # the name to call this argument on help messages
    type=int,     # after parsing, the argument will be of type list<int>
    help='a number to search the minimum in')
# when you are done describing the arguments to the parser, tell it to parse
args = parser.parse_args()

# and here is a simplification of your function using the built-in `min`
print(min(args.numbers))
```

Use it like this:

```
$ python3 main.py 1 2 3 4                                                                 ⏎
1
```